# OpenVPN and gateway on linux

Tags: routing, openvpn, gateway

I have home server with Debian installed

When I turn on openvpn it creates new interface - `tun0`

It also adds some routing rules for that interface, including `0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.101.1 dev tun0`, but I always delete this rule to make `eth0` default interface so everything goes via it by default

I want to setup that server as gateway, and make all data forward from `eth0` to `tun0`

Then I could just change default gateway to server's ip on any device in lan to use vpn

And the question is how can I do this?

Comment: Why are you deleting this route? Do you not want half your traffic routed through the VPN?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I want to route through the VPN only traffic which comes from device which doesn't have enough power to run openvpn client

Comment: Your OpenVPN config is *seriously* boned, amongst other things, if it's dropping /1 routes when you don't want to default route out through the VPN.

Comment: @womble oh wait... I can just change config file?

Comment: @stek29 yes, almost certainly.

Comment: @womble can you provide some links or guides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer to my question:

- Start OpenVPN:

`openvpn --config /path/to/config.file &`

- Wait until it successfully connects:

`until ip l sh tun0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do sleep 1; done`

- Delete rule which makes `tun0` default interface:

`ip route del 0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.101.1 dev tun0`

- Enable ip forwarding:

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

- Enable and configure NAT:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE`

`iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @peterh I should wait 2 days before I could do this